# What are the recommended resources for learning about the Actor model of concurrent systems?

Tags: concurrency, actor-model

The Actor concurrency model is clearly gaining favor. Is there a good book that presents the patterns and pitfalls of the model? I am thinking about something that would discuss, for instance, the problems of consistency and correctness in the context of hundreds or thousands of independent Actors.

It would be okay if it were associated with a specific language (Erlang, I would imagine, since that seems universally regarded as the proven implementation of Actors), but I am hoping for something more than an introductory chapter or two. I'm actually most interested in Actors as they are implemented in Scala, if there are any such resources available.

Answer (score 6):

There is a good article here: [Concurrency in Erlang and Scala](http://ruben.savanne.be/articles/concurrency-in-erlang-scala).

There are several references at the end, including books, but there is a good example in [Scala by Example](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

[Actors in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/actors_in_scala) is dedicated to Actors programming model. It discusses many subjects like Event-based programming, exceptions handling, remote actors and distributed and parallel programming.
You may want to have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from [Actors in scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/actors_in_scala), there are some chapters that discuss Actors in Scala in these books: [Programming in Scala (Artima)](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed) and [Programming Scala (O'Reilly)](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/).

Furthermore, you could take a look at Akka documentation: [Akka](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/)